# Vite: Internal server error using inertia in a Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I installed [Inertia.js](https://inertiajs.com/upgrade-guide) in my Laravel project. I followed all the steps from the server side to the client side. All the steps were going well until I wanted to run the project. I ran [`php artisan serve`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) and in another terminal, I ran `npm run dev`, but this error appeared. I don't know why.

> 11:12:36 a.m. [vite] Internal server error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.

I installed that package, @vitejs/plugin-vue, but everything is still the same.